# Select all keys except some key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I Only know one key from dictionary and I want to Select all other key that are present.

I don't want to remove the `KeyValue` pair that I know but want to select rest.

For example, I have:

```
Key:Health
Value: 123

Key:Vision
Value: 345

Key:Dental
value:567
```

and I know that Health will be there. So I want to select all other `Keyvalue` pairs except `Key:Health`

Could any one suggest a C# code to implement this ?

Comment: What did you try? anything??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var allKeyValuesButHealth = dict.Where(kv => kv.Key != "Health");
```

Since this is a deferred executed LINQ query it's a good idea to materialize it with `ToList`, `ToArray` or even `ToDictionary` if you want to use it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var k in theDictionary.Keys)
{
    if(k == "Health") 
        continue;
    else
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

the continue will skip the one you want to ignore and you can just access the others as theDictionary[k].